# docker repo for cent06 is not available

Tags: centos, docker

Trying to install docker on  a VMWare guest CentOS 6 based on the documents of docker.

Upon running the script `sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`, it gives the message

```
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/6/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
```

checked the link https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/6/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml and it returns error 404. Checked the docker site and CentOS 6 is not on the list.

What I tried:
Downloaded the docker repo and updated the baseURL to a mirror site.

```
[docker-ce-stable]
name=Docker CE Stable - $basearch
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg
```

then added it to my repo

```
sudo yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    /home/username/Desktop/DOCKER PROJECT/docker-ce.repo
```

Tried to reinstall but got the message:

```
Repository '_home_username_Desktop_DOCKER': Error parsing config: Error parsing "baseurl = '/home/username/Desktop/DOCKER'": URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
```

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#os-requirements: "To install Docker Engine, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7."

Comment: Oh. I did not read it. That was my mistake. Thank you for pointing it out. 
currently trying the instructions on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134196/installing-docker-on-centos-6-after-removal-of-docker-io link

Answer (score 0):

On visiting to the repo of docker for centOs

`https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/`

you can see they don't have `docker` packages for Centos Version (7.0-7.9) and (8.0-8.9) there are no packages for any version 6 CentOs so its throwing 404 file not found error.

you can upgrade your centos to version 7 or 8 and follow steps given on `https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/` it will work well after that.